# Symfony login form doesn't work

Tags: symfony, security, authentication

In my Symfony project I have a members zone accessible only by logged users then I write this in my security.yml (access_control):

```
{ path: ^/membre/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

I did too a form with fos_user_security_check action and a `_target_path = detail_page_membre`.

When I try to log my user, I was redirected to `/` and in my log I have this:

> User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"toto"} []
>   Matched route "detail_page_membre".
>   Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
>   Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to
>    authentication entry point.

I don't have write any firewalls maybe it's this?

Comment: Could you maybe show your complete `security.yml`?

Comment: Yes it here  : https://pastebin.com/NEbUi28Z

Answer (score 0):

This issue often happens because of the session:

check your session configuration under framework in config.php file:

```
framework:
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
```

Read more:

1. [Logging in redirects to the login page with no errors](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1921)
2. [Symfony2 - Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862128/symfony2-access-is-denied-user-is-not-fully-authenticated)

Comment: Its bizarre because if i try to connect with 'toto' user its not work (i see anon in the debug bar) but if i go to /admin it say denied and now i can see 'toto' login in the debug bar